# createBottomTabNavigator transitionConfig

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i'm studying react-native by cloning instagram.

There is any way apply transitionConfig to createBottomTabNavigator(react-navigation)?
I know there is no transitionConfig in [document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html). 
but i want to slide up the page just like instagram's upload

```js
const Footer = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Upload: { screen: Upload  },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    transitionConfig: TransitionConfiguration,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 6):

createBottomTabNavigator do not have transitionConfig. To enable transition when clicking on the nav bar, I made the following workaround.

First put the Upload screen into a StackNavigator, and set tabBarOnPress as follow:

```
const UploadStack = createStackNavigator({
        Upload: Upload
});

UploadStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}) => { navigation.navigate('ModalUpload') }
}
```

Then put this stack in the BottomTabNavigator

```
const Footer = createBottomTabNavigator({ 
    Home: Home,
    UploadStack: UploadStack
});
```

Finally put the BottomTabNavigator and the Upload screen into a StackNavigator with the transitionConfig:

```
export default createStackNavigator({
    Footer: Footer,
    ModalUpload: Upload

}, {headerMode: 'none', transitionConfig: TransitionConfiguration})
```

Comment: Your answer has given me a lot of light on my problem. But if I call "ModalUpload" the bottomTab will not load.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you help me. I put you in context of my problem. I have a bottomTab of 4 tabs. I want to achieve a transition when I click on each tap. The problem is that at the same time I have a `drawer` and within this, I have my bottomTab. I hope you can give me an example and you can help me.

Comment: the furthest I've come is to load some tab of my bottomTab but when I navigate, the bottomTab is lost